# How can force an R project to use my current libraries instead of installing new ones?

Tags: r, package, project

I have downloaded a zip file containing an R project.
If I open the xxx.Rproj file R forces it opens some kind of environment with no packages installed, it forces me to install all packages again.
But I have a problem, I don't have administrator rights to do it.

How can I force R to ignore all this and just use my current packages.

The project includes an .lock file, a renv folder and other.

Comment: Administrator rights should not be required for installing R packages. What error are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root of the project folder should also include `.Rprofile` , depending on your system / setup it may or may not be "hidden" . This is what activates `renv`.
You can open it and remove or comment

```r
source("renv/activate.R")
```

line.
Or rename / remove the `.Rprofile` file itself, if it doesn't include anything else that might have an effect on that specific project.